# How to move the camera node to follow the plane Node

Tags: swift

I have a plane Node and a camera Node currently in my scene. The plane could be manoeuvred by a joystick however currently when I begin to move the plane, the camera doesn't follow it and eventually it fades from view. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to keep updated: the camera has a position and a direction its looking.  I assume you want some kind of chase camera and if so you can create a [SCNLookAtConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint) that targets your node, which will keep the camera pointed at the plane.  Then you can set a [SCNDistanceConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scndistanceconstraint) which will keep your camera following your plane.